# How can I combine shift element function to insertion sort?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I have a question: I was asked to write a function which related to insertion sort. By giving a number the function will shift the next i values to the right, and to notice that the value at the last of the "i values" will get overrun by the previous one. For example:
9,8,7,6,5 and the number is i = 2:
will become:9,8,7,7,6
while 5 got overrun.

So far that's the code I wrote:

```
    public static void shift(int [] arr, int i) {
    if(i < arr.length / 2) {
        for(int j = i + i; j > i; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
        }
    }

    else {
        for(int j = arr.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to combine it with insertion sort and I tried with no success.
Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Please give another example, still I don't get the question right. Say, For 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and i=3 what would be values after shifting?

Comment: should be: 2,3,4,5,5,6

Answer (score 0):

What I got so far, I could be wrong, in that case please make comment so that I can correct.

```
public static void shift(int [] arr, int i) 
   {
      if(i <= arr.length-2)  //  when i > (arr.length-2) shifting doesn't make any effect
      {
         int tmp = arr[i+1];    //  tmp will hold the overwritten element for future use. 
         arr[i+1] = arr[i];
      }
   }
```

Now, do you want to sort it by insertion-sort?

Comment: I were asked not to swap elements, but shift them right as I mention above

Comment: It's not swap, I shift it right. you can hide the "int tmp = arr[i+1];" statement. a swap includes three statements.